# I arrived when he had (already) left

Tags: word-order

Is it true that "I arrived **when** he had (already) left." is wrong?

It (supposedly) should be:

> **When I arrived he had (already) left.**

Is it really a mistake which natives don't usually make or is it just one of those rules which is written for students and neglected by natives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence is correct and natural.

"When he had left" is an adverbial time clause that refers to the period of time starting from the time he left.

Answer (score 2):

It's clear that if he had already left, you arrived AFTER his departure. So WHEN is wrong here.

However, you could say: **WHEN I arrived, he had already left.**

Comment: OK, it's clear that it's clear. But why is it WRONG?

Comment: It would be more natural to say "I arrived **after** he had left." But **when** doesn't seem glaringly wrong to me.

Comment: @KateBunting - _I'm sorry that I never knew Anelka, because I arrived when he had already left._ The Guardian, 2001 - _I arrived when he had already half finished. I was not present at the beginning_ The Invention of Eyeglasses (Edward Rosen) Journal of the History of Medicine and Allied Sciences Vol. 11, No. 1 (January, 1956) - _the otter was a very respected animal, and I arrived when he had just finished cooking one._ Report of Hudson Bay Programme (Canada)